# lostpassword_url filter not working with wordpress and bbpress combo

Tags: wordpress, reset-password

Following hook not work when I use bbpress with wordpress,

```
function passurl_update($lostpassword_url, $redirect ) {
  return site_url().'/forgot-password/';
}
add_filter('lostpassword_url', 'passurl_update', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict user from accessing default lost password page

```
   function my_redirect_home( $lostpassword_redirect ) {
        $lostpass_page =site_url().'/lost-password/';
        wp_redirect($lostpass_page);
        exit;

    }

 add_filter( 'lostpassword_redirect', 'my_redirect_home' );
```